# SOC 2 Type 1 Report for Salesforce via Python

Tags: python, simple-salesforce

How can I download the SOC 2 Type 1 report from compliance.salesforce.com via Python API or SDK?
Here is the report URL:
https://compliance.salesforce.com/en/documents/a005A00000uKyHxQAK

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried already and what hasn't worked with your approach? I'd also question why you would need to download these via API in the first place? Could you please [edit] your question to add more details.